# Can Javascript do this

Tags: javascript

make this:

```
/*this can't run*/
var o = {first:1};
function f(arg,o){
   /*
    can i do something make this function's this=o
   */
   alert(arg+this.first);
}
f(2,o);
```

equal this:

```
var o = {
  first:1,
  f:function(arg){
    alert(arg+first);
  }
}
o.f(2);
```

and I know we can use this:

```
f.apply(o,1);
```

but I want to handle all things in f:

```
function f(arg,o){
    /*magic*/
    alert(arg+this.first);
}
```

Comment: What's the question? Have you tried this yourself?

Comment: Have you tried it?  That's pretty much a requirement for asking this type of question.  Try it and tell us what you don't understand about the results.

Comment: Do what of what? See http://stackoverflow.com/faq for help in asking questions if you're new.

Comment: You edited, good thing, but I'm missing the question, still.

Comment: I'm so sorry.But my english is poor.I don't know how to explain my question.So so sorry.I will try my best to explain it.

Comment: I think he's asking how to create a method on the object. His example is fine, he just forgot `this` before `first`.

Comment: I think what the OP is looking for is scope binding. e.g. an implementation for Function.prototype.bind(scope).

Comment: So, something like: `Function.prototype.bind = function (scope) { var that = this; return function () { return that.apply(scope, arguments); }; }; f = f.bind(o);`

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you mean:

```
var o = 
{ 
  first : 1, 
  f : function(arg)
  { 
    alert(arg + this.first);
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 Bravo for understanding what was asked!

Comment: I think the OP wants to bind the globally declared function `f` to `o`'s scope.

Comment: Yes, that's what i want to say...Thank you~I want to know if i can change a function's scope to one of it's parameters.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to change `this` to a parameter to the function. If you have access to the function's source, you might as well access the other object's properties directly as `o.prop` instead of `this.prop`. But, you can certainly create a new function that is bound to a given scope. See my comment to your original question.

Comment: thank you very much.That's what i want to do.Now I can use f like this:[code]xhrPost("url",load:f);//now f can handle responseText in o[/code]